# How to put my database schema (.mwb) on mysql server on ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I have a my sql server running on my ubuntu 16.04 server and created on my local mysql workbench a new database schema (.mwb file).
My question is how to make my mysql server on ubuntu run my database schema?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL workbench [does exist for Linux](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-linux.html). Did you try to load your file?

Comment: File=>Open? Do you have any experience with mysql?